# how to include excluded folder in android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-arctic-fox

i accidentally deleted my folder by selecting "mark directory as exclude", how do i make the missing folder reappear, I've tried looking in android studio settings, but can't find anything about how to include again

Comment: i can't find .iml file on my project, and there is not option to cancel exclusion

Comment: It's not in your project, it's inside `.idea` folder which is excluded from your project too. You can find it with file manager

Comment: thanks a lot, philip, you save my day